# Solve following differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve following 2nd order differential equation.

$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} - 2\tan{x}\frac{dy}{dx} + 5y = 0$

Comment: Can we know if you have tried something yet?

Comment: I tried to resolve tanx into sin and cos and then put respective series of both. And i took y as power series about x=0.

Answer (score 2):

Multiplication by $\cos x$ gives $y''\cos x-2y'\sin x+5y\cos x=0$, but with $z=y\cos x$, the LHS is $z''+6z$. This gives immediately $z=A\sin\sqrt{6}x+B\cos\sqrt{6}x$, and thus
$$y=A\frac{\sin\sqrt{6}x}{\cos x}+B\frac{\cos\sqrt{6}x}{\cos x}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Wolfram Mathematica gives
$$y(x)=C_1e^{-i\sqrt 6x}\sec x+\frac{C_2ie^{-i\sqrt 6x}\sec x}{2\sqrt 6}$$
as general solution. Also you can show that $y_1=\cos(\sqrt 6 x)\sec x$ is a solution and then find another solution $y_2(x)$ by using reduction of order.

Comment: This is not Stack Exchange Mathematica.